# MS Word set OutlineDemote to text after specific word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to set the whole text after a specific word in a word file to OutlineDemote.

My VBA script is setting the whole document to OutlineDemote.

What am i doing wrong?

```
Sub FormatFeatures()

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="Test", _
    Forward:=True

If myRange.Find.Found = True Then
    myRange.SetRange (myRange.End), ActiveDocument.Content.End
    myRange.Paragraphs.OutlineDemote
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of the found range is within a paragraph. So you need to start the range you're working with from the beginning of the following paragraph:

```
Sub FormatFeatures()

   Dim myRange As Range
   Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

   myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="Test", _
      Forward:=True

   If myRange.Find.Found = True Then
      myRange.SetRange myRange.Next(wdParagraph).Start, ActiveDocument.Content.End
      myRange.Paragraphs.OutlineDemote
   End If
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Screenshot of results

[image]

Comment: I'm a newbie to MSWord VBA. Can you explain why it would be `Start:=myRange.Next(wdParagraph).Start` but `End:=ActiveDocument.Content.End` and not `End:=myRange.Next(wdParagraph).End` ?

Comment: @Toddleson - "to set the whole text after a specific word in a word file to OutlineDemote" - so that would include all the remaining paragraphs in the document, as it does in the OP's code in the question. Your suggestion would only demote the single paragraph that follows the found text.

Comment: but my problem is that this code sets the whole document to OutlineDemote...what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Andreas - "I want to set the whole text after a specific word in a word file to OutlineDemote"  indicates that you want to demote all remaining paragraphs in the document after the found text. If this is not what you want then you need to explain clearly what it is that you do want to happen.

Comment: Dear @TimothyRylatt you are right, i want to set only the text after the found word, but my code as well as your code sets my whole document to outline demote

Comment: @Andreas - "i want to set only the text after the found word" - What exactly does that mean? [`OutlineDemote`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphs.outlinedemote) applies to paragraphs, not text.

Comment: all paragraphs after one word should be set OutlineDemote

Comment: @Andreas - which is exactly what the code in answer does. `myRange` starts at the beginning of the paragraph after the one the found text is in and extends to the end of the document.

Comment: Left before applying your code, right after applying  https://imgur.com/a/5v7xi0P 
My found word is the heading of chapter 12

Comment: @Andreas - it works for me in Office 365.

Comment: very stupid mistake from my side.... obvious, the heading is also listed in the table of contents...and thats why it formatted everything... i am really sorry @TimothyRylatt

Additional question :) how can i make sure that it takes the second search result of the word?

Comment: @Andreas - add `ActiveDocument.Fields.ToggleShowCodes` at the start and end of the routine.